# Re-executing program and restoring variables from within the program itself (Python)

Tags: python, variables, exception

So main() is a game loop which runs the game. Whenever the GameOver exception is raised inside the game loop (when you die in battle, for example), I would like to prompt the player to either QUIT the game or start a NEW game. If you start a new game, it works well, besides one major flaw - all variables that have changed so far stay changed. Basically from the exception, the main() loop is re-ran but it does not reset the variables as they are already altered during the program execution.

Is there a way to reset the values of the variables and pretty much, in a way, reread all the python files without having to re-execute the script itself?

I have got this code:

```
while True:
    try:
        main()
    except GameOver:
        a = game_over_prompt()
        if a == "quit":
            quit()
        else:
            print("\n" * 50)
            print("┌──────────────────────┐")
            print("│ Starting a new game! │")
            print("└──────────────────────┘")
            print()
            loading(30)
```

Comment: what's `loading`? Sounds like `main` doesn't initialize game state, or else this would work fine

Comment: Re-initialize them to default values in a method ran whenever a new game is called.

Comment: If your game-state is stored in local variables this would already be working. Don't use globals. Alternatively if your game-state is stored in a file for persistence you'll want to have an initial state file that you can copy over each time the game restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a function that resets all the variables, and then calling it before starting a game. It's as simple as that.

To get a little fancier, and to make this perhaps a bit easier, use a special purpose class to hold all your game data. Then, for each game you create a new instance of this class and throw away the old instance.

```
class GameData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.board_size = (100,100)
        self.score = 0
        ...

def main():
    gamedata = GameData()
    ...
    if (something):
        gamedata.score += 1
    ...
```